# How can I fill this gap between two areas of flooring 

Tags: flooring

I have two half-inch gaps in the flooring in my kitchen.  One between the kitchen and the living room (first image) and another between the kitchen and the outside door (second image)!
[image: Kitchen and living room]

[image: Kitchen and outside]

at their widest the gaps are an inch wide and about a half inch deep at the deepest.  The tile on the kitchen to living room gap starts about a quarter of an inch higher than the threshold, and finishes about a quarter of an inch lower.

What is the best way to fill these gaps?  I'm willing to live with some visual imperfections.

Comment: Only the second image is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: T-Moulding]
You could use a T-Moulding/Transition Strp

Are the surfaces the same level?  If not, you could use a reducer strip
[image: Reducer strip]

Both come in various widths, heights, lengths, materials, colors.

Answer (score 2):

**Upper Picture** - there is a saddle, but it is not doing what it is supposed to do - transition fully from one room/floor to another.  You could remove that saddle and get a wider one that covers the full gap. An issue may be the relative height between the two areas.  If they are uneven, you might need to put a filler under the saddle that levels them.  This should be a molding made of the same wood as the saddle and stick out slightly beyond the saddle on the lower side (maybe 1/2" to 1").  it needs to be tapered to avoid a sharp transition.

**Lower Picture** - There does not appear to be any saddle creating a close seal between the bottomn of the door and the floor.  This is an area that needs attention to avoid insulation problems, moisture seepage and even insect incursion. There shoudl be a saddle that reaches the outside floor level. Again, uneven levels require some build up generally *under* the main saddle. The gap is less of an issue than *bridging* the gap.

Answer (score 0):

For the gap at the living room try a stained piece of 1/4 round next to the threshhold and some grout to fill in the space that is left. For the outside door area look in the wood laminate trim area at the home store for a piece of edge trim similar to what you have at the other problem area. You can maybe find something with a stepped profile that will match the tile height.

Comment: I wouldn't fill the entire gap with grout, the floor needs to be able to expand/contract and move without causing cracking or buckling.